# WMIC Process List and then terminate?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, terminate, wmic

**EDIT** @aschipfl - You response is perfect!  Answer is below.

HISTORY..
Why do this?  99.9% of the time, we are able to simply just perform the following:

```
WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" CALL stopservice
```

And it works fine.  However, there has been an occasion, where we would have Tomcat stay in memory and not stop.  So we have to terminate it.  I have to add "signature" files provided from our vendor in once a month on about 40 servers and I must be 100% sure that I am able to do so without issue.  Most of our issues seem to be with Tomcat7 and JDK7 with some memory tweaking.

I have the following in my batch script, which both of these work great.

```
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "CommandLine Like '%%tomcat%%'" CALL Terminate
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "CommandLine Like '%%java%%'" CALL Terminate
```

However, I would really prefer not to terminate tomcat6w.exe or tomcat7w.exe.  What I really want to do is to terminate tomcat?.exe, but not terminate: tomcat?w.exe

When I tried the following, I just killed my server - doh!!

```
WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" get processid | WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "processid = processid" CALL Terminate
```

I think I can do the following, but is not working yet:

```
for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" get processid') do set pid=%%a
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "processid = %pid%" CALL Terminate
```

However, since I am doing a wildcard with tomcat, I think it is adding an extra Carriage return..

Ref..  I did find some interesting info here:
http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3815

Hope this makes sense?

**Answer**

```
FOR /F "skip=1" %%a IN ('WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" get processid') DO (
FOR /F "delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET pid=%%b
)
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "processid = %pid%" CALL Terminate
pause
```

Thanks!

Comment: The extra carriage-return comes from the `wmic` command (independet on whether you are using wildcards or not); `wmic` outputs Unicode text, the conversion to ASCII by `for /F` does not work perfectly; to get rid of it, simply wrap another `for /F` loop around: `for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" get processid') do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set pid=%%b`

Comment: Awesome!  That is what i was looking for.

Comment: Great! I just posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra carriage-return comes from the `wmic` command (independent on whether you are using wildcards or not). `wmic` outputs Unicode text, the conversion to ASCII by `for /F` does not work perfectly.

To get rid of the additional carriage-return, simply wrap another `for /F` loop around:

```
for /F "skip=1" %%a in ('WMIC service where "name like 'tomcat%%'" get processid') do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set pid=%%b
```

So the variable `pid` contains the pure process ID value.